# How add geojson features to style in Mapbox android sdk v.11

Tags: java, android, mapbox

I don't know how to add features from `geojson` source in existing loaded layer.

In SDK < 10 it was possible to simply: `style.addSource(GeoJsonSource)`, unfortunately in **v.11** there is no such option.

my code:

```
mapBoxView.getMapboxMap().loadStyle("mapbox://styles/acc/clpk1zhrl00sx01pg9ct401mme", new Style.OnStyleLoaded() {
    @Override
    public void onStyleLoaded(@NonNull Style style) {


        String geoJsonString = "{\n" +
                "  \"type\": \"FeatureCollection\",\n" +
                "  \"features\": [\n" +
                "    {\n" +
                "      \"type\": \"Feature\",\n" +
                "      \"properties\": {},\n" +
                "      \"geometry\": {\n" +
                "        \"coordinates\": [\n" +
                "          9.979275970597428,\n" +
                "          -5.155099071434108\n" +
                "        ],\n" +
                "        \"type\": \"Point\"\n" +
                "      }\n" +
                "    }\n" +
                "  ]\n" +
                "}";
        
        FeatureCollection featureCollection = FeatureCollection.fromJson(geoJsonString);

        GeoJsonSource geoJsonSource = new GeoJsonSource.Builder("markers-source")
                .data(String.valueOf(featureCollection))
                .build();

        style.getStyleSources();
        SymbolLayer symbolLayer = new SymbolLayer("markers-layer", "markers-source");
        symbolLayer.textField("{name}");
        symbolLayer.textSize(16.0);


        ScaleBarUtils.getScaleBar(mapBoxView).setEnabled(false);


    }
});
```